# How to escape complex string with Salt?

Tags: string, escaping, salt-stack

I want to use Salt states to change the `PROMPT_COMMAND` on a network of systems, but I haven't been able to figure out the proper string escaping strategy. The prompt command is:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="`if [[ \$? -eq "0" ]]; then echo "\\[\\033[32m\\]"; else echo "\\[\\033[31m\\]"; fi`\! \[\033[36m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\]\W \[\033[0m\]$ "'
```

First I tried:

```
/etc/bash.bashrc:
  file.append:
    - text:
      - PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="`if [[ \$? -eq "0" ]]; then echo "\\[\\033[32m\\]"; else echo "\\[\\033[31m\\]"; fi`\! \[\033[36m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\]\W \[\033[0m\]$ "'
```

But the state won't compile. I tried twice more (once with single quotes and again with double) by quoting the string and escaping nested instances within. Neither succeeded. Then I placed the directive in a text file (`bashrc.txt`) and tried:

```
/etc/bash.bashrc:
  file.append:
    - source: salt://_fragments/bashrc.txt
```

But this breaks the rendering system also, even though you'll note that I purposefully omit a `- template: jinja` argument.

---

Is there some other escaping mechanism available through Salt or Jinja that will be resilient against the myriad nested ticks, quotes, and backslashes present in this particularly gruesome string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
/etc/bash.bashrc:
  file.append:
    - text: |
        PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="`if [[ \$? -eq "0" ]]; then echo "\\[\\033[32m\\]"; else echo "\\[\\033[31m\\]"; fi`\! \[\033[36m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\]\W \[\033[0m\]$ "'
```

Comment: No, I haven't tried this technique. Is it documented somewhere? It looks like a jinja filter without a name.

Comment: @Chris this is actually plain YAML formatting. See http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/book/1_2/en/05-Configuring-Symfony#chapter_05_sub_yaml_syntax_and_symfony_conventions for for more information.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the accepted answer is to use jinja2 tags:

```
{% raw %}
string
{% endraw %}
```